# How to make Input POST as variable in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I pass name_cust variable using POST to the controller (this is works) and want to echoing the variable in the html body.

In the controller,

```
$data['nameCust'] = $this->input->post('name_cust');
```

In the body php,

```
<p class="lead">Are you sure want to delete <?php echo $nameCust; ?></p>
```

When I checked in with firebug it is looks good in XHR Response HTML, the snapshot is in https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtN8S.png

But... not with actual HTML response, the snapshot is in https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Qvm.png

Or, did I miss something?Thanks

**EDIT:**

```
class Dbcust extends CI_Controller {

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('dbcust_model');
    $this->load->helper('url');
  }

  public function index($page = 'all')
  {
    if(! file_exists( 'application/views/cust/dom/dom-'.$page.'.php' ))
    {
      show_404();
    }    

    switch ($page)
     {
     case 'all':
      $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_dbcust();
      break;
     case 'gold':
      $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_dbcust_gold();
      break;
     case 'platinum':
      $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_dbcust_platinum();
      break;
     case 'diamond':
      $data['cust'] = $this->dbcust_model->get_dbcust_diamond();
      break;
     default:
      break;
    }   

    $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);

    $data['nameCust'] = $this->input->post('name_cust'); // -> Here it is my declaration

    $this->load->view('cust/template/head',$data);
    $this->load->view('cust/template/body',$data);
    $this->load->view('cust/template/foot');
    $this->load->view('cust/dom/dom-'.$page);
  }
```

And the ajax caller:

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>dbcust',  
            data: {name_cust: name_cust},  
            success: function() {

            }
```

Comment: Can you post the controller code?

Comment: Are you using ajax for this? We have no idea what is going on unless you post all the relevant code

Comment: Sure, and yes Im using ajax...sorry for being late replying you all. I have edit my question. Thanks

Comment: please note that `function index() {}` does not take any parameters, you need to use `_remap()` function to make it work. Also you can make your switch nicer with {} brackets `$this->dbcust_model->get_dbcust_{$page}();` (put this in default case of switch and delete all remaining except "all" case)

Comment: Im not using `_remap()` but using `$route['dbcust/(gold|platinum|diamond)'] = "dbcust/index/$1";` in my routes.php and everything looks good except what I asked here. Is there really any relation with it?

Comment: Try playing with `success: function (blabla) {$(document.body).html(blabla)}` in my ajax make the response replacing the original, but I lost my css & js functionality. Can someone pointing me out?